# Postgis binary geometry to json in C# code behind

Tags: c#, postgresql, postgis, geojson

Postgis is stroring geometry data as binary format in database like this:

[image]

This is an SQL query result of `select * from mytable`

Postgis query helpers shows me this binary data as text. (like ST_AsText)

But I want to convert this binary data with C# code behind. I will get the SQL result and convert the binary data to text or GEOJSON. is this possible?

Comment: have a look at st_astext for storing geometry in well-known text format or alternativly with st_asgeojson for converting to GeoJSON.

Comment: I wonder if there any way to convert C# codebase, I know your suggestions.

Comment: @bookmarker this is a start: http://www.dupuis.me/node/28

Comment: If you allready know the SQL-functions to call where exactly is your problem? Don´t you know how to execute an SQL-command within C#? What results do you get? Or any erros? Please be more specific on what you´ve allready done, in particular provide some code that shows your affords and where you´re stuck.